# Winforms App hosted on WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I need host a WinForms app on WPF app. I followed the steps [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31429/Embedding-a-NET-WinForms-Application-in-an-Interne), but I've an error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
>   Message: Se produjo una excepción en el destino de la invocación.

What's wrong? I'm using VS2012 and .NET 4.5. The WinForms App is only a `Form` with a `Button`. The event click show a `MessageBox` with a message `Hello World` nothing more.

Comment: post your code and XAML.

Comment: Also, what do you want that for? it looks like a horrible hack.

Answer (score 1):

I have used WindowsFormsIntegration.dll before and it works fine. this should help you get started. Add a reference to WindowsFormsIntegration first. then...

```
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
```

...

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new Form1();
        form.TopLevel = false;

        WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        host.Child = form;
        host.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        host.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;


        grid.Children.Add(host);
    }
```

...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and now for the simple winform

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
}
```